# PostgreSQL: Neater way to insert rows into a table with many (20+) columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, sql-insert, key-value

For example, if I do something like:

```
INSERT INTO Table (Col1, Col2, Col3, ... Col25) VALUES
  ('valA1', 'valA2', 'valA3', ..., 'valA25'),
  ('valB1', 'valB2', 'valB3', ..., 'valB25'),
  ('valC1', 'valC2', 'valC3', ..., 'valC25'),
...
```

It's hard to tell at a glance that valA12 or valB12 correspond to Col12. Is there a neater way in postgres to put the column name next to the value, something like:

```
INSERT INTO Table VALUES
  (Col1:'valA1', Col2:'valA2', Col3:'valA3', ..., Col25:'valA25'),
  (Col1:'valB1', Col2:'valB2', Col3:'valB3', ..., Col25:'valB25'),
  (Col1:'valC1', Col2:'valC2', Col3:'valC3', ..., Col25:'valC25'),
...
```

?

Comment: No, the first version is your only option. Some SQL clients can display hints which value belongs to which column though.

Comment: Depends on what you are using to do the `INSERT`. In Python using `psycopg2` you can pass a dictionary to the query that would be a mapping of the column to its value.